# Computation between two large columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe that has 2 columns of zipcodes, I would like to add another column with their distance values, I am able to do this with a fairly low number of rows, but I am now working with a dataframe that has about 500,000 rows for calculations. The code I have works, but on my current dataframe it's been about 30 minutes of running, and still no completion, so I feel what i'm doing is extremely inefficient.

Here is the code

```
import pgeocode
dist = pgeocode.GeoDistance('us')

def distance_pairing(start,end):
    return dist.query_postal_code(start, end)

zips['distance'] = zips.apply(lambda x: distance_pairing(x['zipstart'], x['zipend']), axis=1)

zips
```

I know looping is out of the question, so is there something else I can do, efficiency wise that would make this better?

Comment: Can you call query_postal_code on the columns rather than on each element? It looks like pgeocode is actually written to allow passing vectors of locations as well as individual locations. This would likely be much faster.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I converted both the columns to lists with string values, and it seems to work much faster, now if I appended this distance list as a column, would it be ordered correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever possible, use vectorized operations in pandas and numpy. In this case:

```py
zips['distance'] = dist.query_postal_code(
    zips['zipstart'].values,
    zips['zipend'].values,
)
```

This won't always work, but in this case, the underlying [`pgeocode.haversine`](https://github.com/symerio/pgeocode/blob/master/pgeocode.py#L350) function is written (in numpy) to accommodate arrays of x and y coordinates. This should speed up your code by several orders of magnitude for a dataframe of this size.